# Use SQL View as datasource in Crystal Reports?

Tags: stored-procedures, view, crystal-reports, datasource

I am using Crystal Reports in my application. Now, I have created an SQL view in my SQL Server database. Can I use this view as data source for Crystal Reports?

I know that we can use a stored procedure as data source for Crystal Reports, but I don't know that we can use a view as data source for the same.

Can any one give me some more ideas regarding the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server Manager:

- Ensure that the grants are set correctly (perhaps SELECT to PUBLIC)

In Crystal Reports:

- Select Database | Database Expert...
- Expand the desired database node
- Expand the 'View' node
- Select desired view

You may link views to other views and also to tables.